# Why is google.script.run is slow?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, client-server, template-engine

So I have a sheet where I added a Custom Menu (that I have searched and found in google).

The Custom Menu shows a dialog (see image below) It returns all the data validation I have in a specific cell, each of which has a checkbox so I can select multiple options and return it in a single cell.

[image: see image here]

**But the FILL CURRENT CELL button runs slow!**

I have here these set of codes:

code.gs

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem('Show Dialog', 'showDialog')
  .addToUi();
}
function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('page').evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .showSidebar(html);
}
var valid = function(){
  try{
    return SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bw-CW5JZX-MEjPKhrWSNA2zWkqJTR6W3yM2yDrqjE_0/edit#gid=0').getRange('B1').getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues()[0].getValues();
  }catch(e){
    return null
  }
}
function fillCell(e){
  var s = [];
  for(var i in e){
    if(i.substr(0, 2) == 'ch') s.push(e[i]);
  }
  if(s.length) SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setValue(s.join(', '));
}
```

page.html

```html
<div style="font-family: arial;">
<? var data = valid(); ?>
<form id="form" name="form">
<? if(Object.prototype.toString.call(data) === '[object Array]') { ?>
<? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
<? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" id="ch<?= '' + i + j ?>" name="ch<?= '' + i + j ?>" value="<?= data[i][j] ?>"><?= data[i][j] ?><br>
<? } ?>
<? } ?>
<? } else { ?>
<p>Maybe current cell doesn't have <a href="https://support.google.com/drive/answer/139705?hl=en">Data validation...</a></p>
<? } ?>
<br>
<br>


<input type="button" value="Fill Current Cell" onclick="google.script.run.fillCell(this.parentNode)" />
<input type="button" value="Clear Selections" onclick="reset()" />
</form>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me so the **FILL CURRENT CELL** button runs faster?

Comment: When "for in" is changed to other loop method, the process cost can be reduced a little. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/3331e1e631d619abef8f32c4be14ba3a) But I cannot understand about `slow` and `faster` you think. So can I ask you about the detail of `slow` and `faster` you think?

Comment: As @Tanaike has said, please consider specifying what you mean with slow and fast. Although take into account that a delay using client-server interaction (`google.script.run` ) is expected. Does it run faster in the editor? Your code seems fine so I don' t know what could be your problem.

Comment: Sorry about that. It takes about 3-5 seconds before the selected items go into the cell. Is it normal? I thought it would be as fast as a second just like when a formula is written directly on the cell..

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that in your case, the effect due to the cost of `google.script.run` is large. By this, even when the formula is used, when `google.script.run` is run, such cost occurs.

Comment: so I guess I just have to get used to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just to leave an answer:

Take into account that `google.script.run` need to interact with server every time is called, therefore you will have some performance issues compared with running the same function directly from the editor.

So if you are experiencing little time difference like you have stated in the comments don't worry as it just normal behavior.